# Avoiding n+1 has_many children should remember parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

When you have a relationship parent child relationship:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end

> parent = parent.find(2)
  Parent Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `parents`.* FROM `parents` WHERE `parents`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
> children = parent.children
  Child Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  `children`.* FROM `children` WHERE `children`.`parent_id` = 2
> children.to_a
  Child Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `children`.* FROM `children` WHERE `children`.`parent_id` = 2
> children.loaded?
 => true
> children.first.parent
  Parent Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `parents`.* FROM `parents` WHERE `parents`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
```

That last line is what is killing me. Why does it hit the database for the parent? Seems like it should remember since the child was loaded through the parent?

Comment: I think that is the way it works.  You might try `inverse_of`, and see if that helps.

Comment: @MarlinPierce I thought I remembered a way to do that! Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that in your case it is the parent that the last line hits the database for? Take a look at the SQL. Does it fetch the parent or does it fetch children again? What you are describing doesn't look like default Rails behaviour. The parent must be cached in your case.

Comment: It definitely hits the database on children.first.parent. The child object, doesnt know the parent without that inverse_of setting.

Comment: @TomRossi  In your case the child must know the parent without any `inverse_of` setting. That is the default behaviour. I understand that `children.first.parent` hits the DB. My question was: Was it really the parent that the DB was hit for? Please, check the actual SQL query

Answer (score 2):

The solution is the use of `inverse_of`:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, inverse_of: :parent
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, inverse_of: :children
end

> parent = Parent.find(foo)
# Fetches the parent
> children = parent.children
# Fetches all children

> children.first.parent   
# No longer fetches the parent again
```

Comment: This should work without the `inverse_of` option. It is the default Rails 5 behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The `belongs_to` association has an option called `inverse_of`, which, if used, establishes a bi-directional association between the models, explicitly, as described in the [API doc for belongs_to](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to). How bi-directional associations work can further be explored [in this API doc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods). 
Basically, if the `Child` model had the association written as `belongs_to :parent, inverse_of: :parent`, the extra query would not have been made.
Do check out [this blog](https://www.viget.com/articles/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations/) for more details about how `inverse_of` works. It provides a very good explanation with examples.

Comment: This should work without the `inverse_of` option. It is the default Rails 5 behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from 4.1, Rails automatically detects the inverse of an association.

See the release notes https://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html

In your case it is not the parent that the last line hit the DB for. The actual SQL query fetched the children since when you access the association in the Rails console and do not actually use the result it is not being cached.

```
parent = Parent.find(foo)
# Fetches the parent:
# Parent Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "parents".* FROM "parents" WHERE ...

children = parent.children
# Fetches all children:
# Child Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "children".* FROM "children" WHERE ...

# the association has not been cached
children.loaded? # => false

# Will fetch children again and again ...

children
# Fetches all children:
# Child Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "children".* FROM "children" WHERE ...

children
# Fetches all children:
# Child Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "children".* FROM "children" WHERE ...

# until you really use them:
children.to_a
children.loaded? # => true

children
# Does not hit the database now
```

So in your case it is children that the DB query was performed for.

```
parent = Parent.find(foo)
# Fetches the parent

children = parent.children
# Fetches all children

children.first.parent   
# Fetches all children again, does not fetch parent as it is automatically inversed

child = children.first

# will not fetch the parent
child.parent
```

Comment: thanks for this! Unfortunately, I'm not seeing it in my Rails 5.2 console. I've updated my question with results and made sure the collection is loaded.